# Why do web-developers still use meta-keywords and meta-description tags?

Tags: meta-tags

**Google is not using meta-keywords tag at all** because keywords are mostly used to spam search engines.

**Google is not using the meta-description tag for ranking.** Sometimes the meta-description tag is used for the site-snippet in search results if part of the content does not fit. But mostly meta-description is generated automatically from the content of the page and meta-description is the same as beginning of the content of the page.

Google has dropped the support of meta-keywords and meta-description tags for search ranking. Google handles about 92% of all search queries in the world. So now web-developers can stop using meta-keywords and meta-description meta tags, because spending time on them is not worth it.

Is there any real benefit for using meta-keywords and meta-description tags?

Links:

- [Google Webmasters Blog about meta tags support by Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html);
- Video with [Matt Cutts about meta tags support by Google](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK7IPbnmvVU);
- [StatCounter Search Engines stats usage](http://gs.statcounter.com/#search_engine-ww-monthly-201103-201203) - Google handles about 92% of all search queries in the world;

Answer (score 0):

No, we should carry on using meta tags, because we don't, and shouldn't be, just supporting Google. The approach should be: make documents as indexable as possible using a search-engine agnostic approach, and then put special handling in for one or two top engines - such as using Google's online tools to improve search ranking.

Google are very dominant in search at present, but there's no guarantee they will always be on top. Maybe it will be Facebook in the future, or perhaps Yahoo/Bing etc. will dramatically improve search quality, and people will switch back.

Side note: for search, I really like [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) at the moment. Lots of nice search shortcuts (see bang operators) and a meaningful privacy policy.

Comment: Meta-keywords and meta-description tags does not make sense for users, because user will not see them in most cases. These tags were made for search engines. But now search engines learned to parse content smart with synonyms. 
What should search engine do if in meta-keywords it sees words "pop-music" but on page there is "classical music"? Does meta-keyword have sense in this case?

Comment: That's a complex question to do with search algorithms, and it depends on the algorithm designer (and the search engine they're working on). In some cases it might add nuance to a search, in other cases it might be keyword stuffing. This is why good search algorithms are so hard to write `:)`.

Comment: IMHO the main idea of Google algorithms is that they try to behave like real user. So for users matter only things, which he can see on page. But, as I said, user will not see meta-keywords and meta-description tags on page so Google stop using it for search ranking.

Comment: @Vitaly - sure, but my reason for continuing to use them isn't to do with Google. It's to do with best practise - if it were extremely costly to maintain meta information, then it might be a good decision to drop it. But in most cases, it doesn't add much cost/time to a site at all.

Comment: Bing uses it as a SEO spam indicator. Quit increasing download times and wasting effort on the dead piece of trash.

Comment: @Fiasco, interesting - can you offer a verifiable source for that in relation to Bing? I should like to explore that further.

Comment: (Andrew made the point in another answer (albeit a year ago) that search engines outside of US/EU still use meta tags - is it your view that this is no longer true?)

Comment: Dan Sullivan, well known SEO and Search Engine goto person in a discussion with Duane Forrester, Bing webmaster outreach project manager. http://searchengineland.com/the-meta-keywords-tag-lives-at-bing-why-only-spammers-should-use-it-96874 Longtime snakeoil filter for anyone doing functional and useful SEO.

Comment: Alright, interesting points @Fiasco. That said, it sounds like Bing's addendum is a tiny bit more cautious than the use of meta tags being a sure sign of spamming. They said: _the main thing people need to keep in mind if they decide to use the [ meta ] tag is to follow the known best practices_. I wonder, if you are aware of what the position is of other major engines, especially outside of the usual EU/US context, perhaps you'd like to offer an expanded answer here?

Comment: When I ask for a list of search engines that use Meta Keywords, I always get a "Buh? but they do" and nothing ever concise, usually anecdotal and never backed up by any search engine help page from the supposed user of the meta tag. Which means that it's devolved to one of those "Cargo Cult" items used by shady SEO operations to try panicking you into using their service because, "OMG YOUR SITE IS MISSING THE META KEYWORDS TAG, MUST BE CURED NOW OR YOUR SITE WILL DIE". Got a couple emails last month telling me that my Google ranking was going to suffer. Bwah hahaha... Yeah sure.

Comment: Also, using the meta keywords tag is a good way to leak your SEO strategy to your competitors.

Comment: @Fiasco, okay, though it's you that is making the claims to certainty here. If you believe that keywords should be dropped, then you need to be aware of what search engines are dominant in which regions, and which of those have a publicly stated position on this. I accept what you say regarding Google and Bing, but there is a very long tail of search engines. I rather like unor's phrase here: a small percentage of a big number is a big number, and that needs to be taken into account when advising sweeping changes for the web.

Answer (score 0):

We should use them because they are there. Who knows - perhaps they will be useful again in the future?

When the W3C drop them we can stop using them.

Just my opinion ofc...

Comment: So lets use [font], [blink], [center] and [marquee] tags. _Who knows - perhaps they will be useful again in the future?_ :)

Comment: @Vitaly - are you picking a fight with people on your very first question? `;-)`

Comment: @halfer Sorry, I did not wanted to be rude. I just wanted to find real reasons for using these tags. I did not find answers in the web and I decided to ask here. I think, these tags does not needed anymore and I explained why. But this is my opinion. So maybe someone here will find better arguments in contrast to mine.
Again, I did not wanted to be rude.

Comment: @Vitaly - no worries, hence the smiley! But you know my view - maybe other people will answer who agree with your position. We'll see...

Comment: @Vitaly - Aren't elements link font and blink officially depreciated? That's why I don't use them. Bring back 'blink' though; I love blink: "The ineluctable modality of the visible"

Comment: IMHO there is no "officiall-things" in web. There is only W3C-suggestions and power of majority.
For example: "text-decoration:blink;" suported in Opera and Firefox, and not supported in Chrome and IE. So which browser choose best position? It is hard to tell.

Comment: @NeilThompson - they're certainly _deprecated_, but I expect their usefulness has depreciated as well `;-)`.

Answer (score 0):

`keywords`:

- Google is not the only search engine. Google market share depends on many factors (country, age, technical know-how, …). Small percentages of big numbers are also big numbers.
- There are special purpose search engines (for niches; only crawling hand-selected sites; etc.) that might still consider it.
- Local search engines might use it. (Local) *full* text search engines anyway.
- Some CMS use it for site search.
- There are other consuming user-agents than search engines, e.g. parser/extractor.

`description`:

- it can be useful even for Google, e.g. when someone searches only for the title/domain of your site, Google would often display snippets like "Login / Register … back to top … please insert CAPTCHA … " etc. If a description is provided, it could be used instead.
- (the points mentionend under `keywords` are relevant for `description`, too.)

Answer (score 0):

If google SEO is your only concern then meta keywords are a complete waste of time, but if you're targeting other search engines it may be worth investigating.

I believe Baidu still uses meta keywords, and that search engine is the dominant player in the Chinese market, so it'd be worth adding meta keywords if you want your site to be popular in China.

Regardless, I wouldn't go stuffing excessive numbers of irrelevant keywords in, as there is every chance that whatever search engine you're targeting will penalise you.  5-7 words summarising your page content is a good starting point.

Comment: Any proof beyond "I believe". I've been doing research and cannot find any search engine willing to state they actually use the Meta Keyword tag for anything. Bing uses it to determine if SEO spamming is being done which is a negative impact.