# META Tags, How to add link to them?

Tags: html, tags, keyword, meta-tags

I have a meta tag as follows...

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword,keyword,keyword">
```

This works fine but I have about 262 keywords to put in and want to link this to a .txt document, is that possible? Is it as simple as...

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords.txt">
```

Any advice would be helpful :)

Thank you

Comment: You might not want so many keywords.

Comment: I agree but the client wants them all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can link it to a document - your example is correct.
As another example taken from w3c:

```
<meta name="DC.identifier" content="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt">
```

The exact specification can be found here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.2

Edit:
Rob mentioned below about search engines sometimes ignoring keywords - another SO post discussing that can be found here:
[Why do web-developers still use meta-keywords and meta-description tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103202/why-do-web-developers-still-use-meta-keywords-and-meta-description-tags)

Comment: The URL is only used as an [identifier](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-identifier) here. The `name` decides what the value of `content` should be/mean. So this cannot be used for `keywords`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#meta-keywords):

> The value must be a set of comma-separated tokens, each of which is a keyword relevant to the page.

- all keywords need to be separated by commas (`,`)
- a keyword must not start or end with a space character (however, you can use leading and trailing whitespace, but it will be stripped, so it cannot be *part* of the keyword)
- a keyword must not *contain* a comma (`,`)

You *can* use a URL as value, but it will not be used as such. It would be simply another keyword string. So in most cases this is not what you want.

The HTML5 spec doesn't limit the length of the `content` attribute, so you are free to include as many keywords as you like. A typical use case could be a local/custom/internal search engine that indexes only the `keywords`.

Most search engines will ignore `keywords` in any case, so it doesn't mattter to them if you have none, 5 or 50. Some (probably older) search enginges *might* lower you ranking or even ban your page if they see such a long list of keywords and think that it's an attempt to spam, but that shouldn't be a problem anymore.